# PCV Valve for Ford Focus 2009

Tags: focus, pcv-valve

I have a Ford Focus 2009 SE 4-Door (2nd generation) at 180 000 km. The maintenance schedule said I need to replace the PCV Valve. I went to the Ford dealer to buy the part but they told me my model doesn't have a valve and there's nothing for me to do.

When I search online I see videos of people replacing the valve on their focus and even this site that has a part number https://www.rockauto.com/en/catalog/ford,2009,focus,2.0l+l4,1443428,exhaust+&+emission,pcv+(positive+crankcase+ventilation)+valve,5052

Does my car have a PCV valve and does it need replacing? Can I trust the part from that website will work?

Comment: So do you have the 2.0 motor version you posted the link of? The are a lot of different motors in Focuses 2009.

Comment: @Daniel yes, updated question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your model has a PCV valve and RockAuto usually sends the right part.  There is some confusion because the part number for the PCV connector hose is the same for the PCV valve itself.  The part numbers are the same because the [PCV valve usually comes together with the tube](https://www.ebay.com/itm/Ford-Focus-Transit-Connect-2-0-PCV-Valve-Hose-New-OEM-Part-8S4Z-6C324-E/122422919196?hash=item1c80f9801c:g:bWEAAOSwB-1Y3XoF).

I would not, however, buy anything but Motorcraft.  I have had too many problems with improper fit or premature failure with other brands.  A genuine Motorcraft PCV valve can be found [here](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B006DZ1NRK) on Amazon.

You are smart to replace the PCV valve.  A clogged one can seriously damage an engine due to excessive blow-by pressure in the crankcase.

Unfortunately, for your car model, replacing the PCV valve is not an easy do-it-yourself job.  It can be done, but go to taurusclub.com for help.

Comment: "A clogged one can seriously damage an engine due to excessive blow-by pressure in the crankcase." Nonsense it will just push back into the air filter box.

Comment: Nonsense?  Really?  There is no way for blow-by gases to enter back into the air filter box.  Those gases can only exit the crankcase via the PCV valve, into the intake manifold.

Comment: Yes nonsense, PCV systems have 2 parts, the pcv valve with pulls out blow by gases from the crankcase into the intake manifold, then a filter to let fresh air into the crankcase. Otherwise you would pull a vacuum on the crank case, they have worked this was since the pcv system was invented.

Comment: Ok, ok, you win.  But, in practice, I've read that a clogged PCV valve increases crankcase pressure to the point of forcing oil droplets past control rings and causing the engine to burn oil.  The excess pressure also causes seals and gaskets to leak.

Comment: Yeah you can read anything on the internet, but until you work on cars for 45 years you learn the truth.